# Using observable with sort data alphabetical

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, observable

i am using angular 8 with asp.net core so i want to display the customer's name in the dropdown list  as alphabetical order from the api service, i found out the only solution to use the observable. is there other way to implement that? and how i can use alphabetical sort in the observable?

```
getAllcustomer() {
    return this._http.get<any>(this.myAppUrl + '/api/users/getcustomer', {responseType: 'json'} )
      .catch(this.errorHandler);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the Observable?

Comment: Can you supply info about the response data?

Comment: The interface is http so you could always use the httpRequest in c#.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see what the current request looks like and then create you own code to mimic the current code.

Comment: @JuliusDzidzevičius the only problem is that i am not familiar with Observable and i do not know to use sort with it

Comment: `...seType: 'json'} ).pipe(map(res => res.sort()))`. `res.sort()` you likely need to modify

Answer (score 0):

You can map the response:

```
getAllcustomer() {
    return this._http.get<any>(this.myAppUrl + '/api/users/getcustomer', {responseType: 'json'} ).pipe(
  // assuming this API call gives you all the customers as an array of strings.
  map((response: any) => response.sort()), 
)
      .catch(this.errorHandler);
}
```

To put this sorting in the service is optional, you can also do the sorting in the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `sort()` method. Quoting [from the MDN reference on `sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the sorted array. The default sort order is ascending, built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values.

**Try with this:**

Add **map** method to your imports:

```
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
// ...
```

Use pipe for concatenate rxjs methods

```
getAllcustomer() {
  return this._http.get<any>(this.myAppUrl + '/api/users/getsuppliers', {responseType: 'json'} ).pipe(
    map(response => response.sort(),
    catchError(this.errorHandler));
}
```

Assuming that response structure is like this:

`['ccc', 'aba', 'aaa']`

Answer (score 0):

Observables, **Simply put**, are a stream of data, we use observales with API calls (in your case asp.net ).

what you are trying to sort is the data (response) that came from the API, not the observable itself. You have two options here, either you sort using pipes (Rxjs operators) in the service itself or you sort a regular JS array in the component (where you subscribe to the observale).

in the service

```
getAllcustomer() {
    return this._http.get<any>(
                    this.myAppUrl + '/api/users/getcustomer',
                    {responseType: 'json'})
            .pipe(
                map(res => res.sort((a,b) => a.name - b.name);),
                catchError(this.errorHandler()) // use catch inside the pipe
            );
}
```

or in the compnent

```
this._customerService.getAllcustomer().subscribe(data => {
     const sortedData = data.sort((a,b) => a.name - b.name);
})
```